# laravel redirect: how to distinguish two routes with same url but different methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-livewire

My post routes are created with

`Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);`

Thus the following routes have the same url but different methods

- posts.destroy url: posts/{post} method: DELETE
- posts.show url:posts/{post} method: GET

I use a confirm deletion modal (livewire-ui/modal) and at some time, I need to redirect from the modal component to the posts.destroy route.

I use this:
`return redirect()->route('posts.destroy',['post'=>$post]);`

but it redirects to the posts.show route.

**How can I redirect to the posts. destroy route ?**

Comment: where is that return line?

Comment: because you are not submitting form request, in delete you submit post request with csrf token and method delete, that's why you are redirected to show route but if you want delete record then you can create your own custom method and call it and redirect from there

Comment: The return line is inside a method that is called by the event listener in the confirm delete modal module. I will try to create a custom method in PostController and redirect to it.

Comment: To submit to a PUT/ PATCH, DELETE or POST routes, you need to submit a form, you can't do it with a redirect or click on a link. But you can delete from the component where you do the redirect now, you don't need to use the resource controller.

Comment: OK. Thank you. it is what I am doing now.